# "undefined local variable or method `user'" in Chapter 10 of Michael Hartl's tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm getting a few errors all of a similar nature and I'm not sure how to fix them. One issue I've been running into is the differences between the new version of the tutorial and the old (I know there are some differences).

My specs are:

Ruby version: 1.9.2p320

Rails version: 3.2.13

Rspec: 2.11.1

Computer: Macbook Pro OS X Mountain Lion

**Errors**

```
5) Micropost pages micropost creation with invalid information should not create a micropost
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button "Post" }.not_to change(Micropost, :count)
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user' for #<MicropostsController:0x007fc7a7c64078>
     # ./app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:5:in `create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) Micropost pages micropost creation with invalid information error messages 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button "Post" }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user' for #<MicropostsController:0x007fc7a7897e90>
     # ./app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:5:in `create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:20:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) Micropost pages micropost creation with valid information should create a micropost
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button "Post" }.to change(Micropost, :count).by(1)
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user' for #<MicropostsController:0x007fc7a7bdfb98>
     # ./app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:5:in `create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:29:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:29:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Micropost_controller.rb**

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user

  def create
    @micropost = current user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
        flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

**micropost_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Micropost pages" do

  subject { page }

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { sign_in user }

  describe "micropost creation" do
    before { visit root_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do

      it "should not create a micropost" do
        expect { click_button "Post" }.not_to change(Micropost, :count)
      end

      describe "error messages" do
        before { click_button "Post" }
        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do

      before { fill_in 'micropost_content', with: "Lorem ipsum" }
      it "should create a micropost" do
        expect { click_button "Post" }.to change(Micropost, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote "current user" in your controller source code.  I bet you meant to write `current_user`.  Identifiers in computer programming almost never have spaces in them.